# Inno Setup: creating custom wizard page AFTER component selection

Tags: inno-setup, wizard

I'm building an installer in Inno Setup. The installed software is a web application server, it checks whether port 80 is free, if it is taken, then it prompts user for another port to use for the web server.

I want this to be shown on a custom wizard page, **just before file copying**. The reason is that it is possible that the user has not selected the "Web server" component at the beginning of the installation, in which case this prompt should not be shown (since it is useless).

I have only managed to create a custom wizard page that appears at the beginning of the install, before the user gets to select what components he wants to install. I want it to appear after the component selection page.

I'm currently looking into using a messagebox instead of a custom wizard page. It's not as fancy but should do it. Also considering going back to InstallJammer, which was my previous platform. I know InstallJammer can be pretty cool (especially in these cases - that is creating custom panes and actions) but some things made me look elsewhere.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind... I think I found the solution:

> Prototype: function
>   CreateInputQueryPage(const
>   **AfterID**: Integer; const ACaption, ADescription, ASubCaption: String):
>   TInputQueryWizardPage;

I'll give it a try now

Edit:
Yep it works I set **AfterID** to **wpSelectComponents**

I now need to find a way to test port 80...